# Does "are previously proposed" make sense in this sentence?

Tags: tense, time-reference

Does this sentence make sense considering that it is in the present tense and the presence of previously in it? Is there a better sentence for it?

> Plenty of solutions are previously proposed to address the problem.

Comment: You're probably better off using the present perfect tense here: ***Plenty of solutions have been previously proposed to address the problem.***

Comment: Please include more information why this is difficult or why you find it confusing.  Otherwise the question may be closed as *proofreading*.

Comment: The question already mentions the source of confusion: using present tense with previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense. "Are" is present tense, and you are clearly using past. Therefore you should change it out to "Were", "Have been" or something similar.

> Plenty of solutions have been previously proposed to address the problem

If actually supposed to be present tense, say this:

> Plenty of solutions are being proposed to address this problem

Comment: Which one of were and have been is better in this context?

Comment: +Shayan use "Have been" in this case